# Api call works via postman but, not in Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I am making an api call to my server via my flutter app but, I keep getting a 503 error saying that my token is incorrect. But, I have verified that it is correct. I am also able to make the api call via Postman.

Via post man I can place an order no problem:

[image]

But when I make the same api call via my app:

```
Future<dynamic> createOrder(
    String stripeToken, accessToken, restaurantId, address, order) async {
  var url = 'https://buddies-8269.herokuapp.com/api/customer/order/add/';

  // print(url);

  final Map<String, dynamic> createOrder = {
    'access_token': accessToken,
    'stripe_token': stripeToken,
    'restaurant_id': restaurantId,
    'address': address,
    'order_details': order,
  };

  print(json.encode(createOrder));

  http
      .post(url,
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: json.encode(createOrder))
      .then((http.Response response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
      print(response.request);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  });
}
```

The data that is being sent up in the call is:

```
{"access_token":"ITgL7UElbR5GU7oeerVEr3UZKiG5AV","stripe_token":"tok_visa_debit","restaurant_id":10,"address":"55 Glenwood, brooklyn NY, 32133","order_details":[{"product_size":47,"quantity":2}]}
```

I get this error in the app:

```
oauth2_provider.models.DoesNotExist: AccessToken matching query does not exist.
sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/api/customer/order/add/" host=buddies-8269.herokuapp.com
```

I do not understand why I can make the call via postman but, not via the app.

Comment: Remove the content type header and just use `body: createOrder` . In postman you aren't encoding the form as JSON, so do the same in Dart.

Comment: I'm getting a cast error that says "(type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)"

Comment: Change 'restaurant_id': restaurantId to 'restaurant_id': restaurantId.toString()

Comment: That wouldn't work because order_detail is a list. Then there would be an issue there

Comment: You need to convert that to a string like you show in the postman screenshot

Comment: Wouldn't Application/json encode it? In the screenshot you can see the content type being exactly that. Also, when I sign in with the token initially, I am using an encoded body and the     "Content-Type": "application/json"
. So why would that be an issue now?

Comment: You tried that and it didn't work. What you show in the screenshot is a traditional form. (It does *not* show JSON, even though the content type is erroneously set to application/json.) Form pairs are always a string name and a string variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to add the `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header when using form data.

Comment: Try just sending the map through as the body without encoding it. Also add the content-type header from above.

Comment: The error is now a with string to int. Postin screenshot now

Comment: "_CastError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)" is the error now once I removed everything